# MySQL search method through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quick question on a method to search mysql database with php.

Right now, I have a function that is supposed to search and return results. Say I have two databases, one being User and one being Profile. User stores the username, email, password. while Profile stores user first name, last name, address, birth day. Right now, I'm not sure how to go about this, but this is what I have so far.

I want to be able to search both tables and return a list of results via a table which I've got covered, but I don't know how to get the intricacies down.
The function will contain either NULL or value of the variable. Right now, this is my sketch up:

```
if(!empty($username)):
$append .= "WHERE";
$append .= "username = ".$username."";
endif;
if(!empty($email)):
$append .= "WHERE";
$append2 .= "email= ".$email."";
endif;
if(!empty($firstname)):
$append .= "WHERE";
$append2 .= "firstname = ".$firstname."";
endif;
if(!empty($lastname)):
$append .= "WHERE";
$append2 .= "lastname= ".$lastname."";
endif;

$sql = "select * FROM Users ".$append."";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$sql2 = "select * FROM Profile ".$append2."";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
$userId = mysql_fetch_row($result2);
$userId['id'] = $id; <-- this is the one I will call to display data.
```

How can I efficiently do this and search/return all unique/distinct user ID's? Both tables include a user ID / incremented ID number (User table is User_ID, Profile table is acct_id). I know this code is a bit wrong... Don't worry about escaping - I;'ve gotten that sorted. Should I use a JOIN statement?

Other problem I am facing is changing between WHERE and AND because sometimes if one var is set but another isn't, then we must use AND instead of just one WHERE. Any idea how to tackle this issue?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: can't you merge the tables? seems pointless to store the first name, last name ... separately.

Comment: I'm sure that was put into consideration, but there are too many rows right now to do anything like that :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `WHERE` clause it is probably best to use arrays and then [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) like this

```
$and_where = array();
if (!empty($username))
    $and_where[] = "username = ".$username;
if (!empty($email))
    $and_where[] = "email = ".$email;
//etc
if (count($and_where) > 0)
    $where = " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $and_where);
else
    $where = "";
```

Are the two tables related in some matter? If `acct_id` is a foreign key to `User_id` you can just use an [`INNER JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) (`$where` as shown above)

```
$query = "SELECT Users.col, ..., Profile.col, ... FROM Users
    INNER JOIN Profile ON Users.user_id = Profile.acct_id".$where;
```

If they aren't, you could simply [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) them

```
$users_and_where = array();
$profiles_and_where = array();
if (!empty($username))
    $users_and_where[] = "username = ".$username;
if (!empty($email))
    $users_and_where[] = "email = ".$email;
//etc
if (!empty($firstname))
    $profiles_and_where[] = "firstname = ".$firstname;
if (!empty($lastname))
    $profiles_and_where[] = "lastname = ".$lastname;
//etc
if (count($users_and_where) > 0)
    $users_where = " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $users_and_where);
else
    $users_where = "";
if (count($profiles_and_where) > 0)
    $profiles_where = " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $users_and_where);
else
    $profiles_where = "";
$query = "(SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM Users".$users_where.")
    UNION
        (SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM Profile".$profiles_where.")";
```

---

You should try to avoid `*` in your queries and select the rows specifically, this way you don't have too much overhead in the future, when additional columns are introduced that your code doesn't use here.